# how to move and scale image by dragging it's edges?

Tags: java, image, swing, mouselistener

I have post this question before also but this time I have added only required and necessary code only although the code is somewhat lengthy.
I want to load image in Jlabel and then after change image when user clicks next button. And when user want to move or scale image he can just easily do it by selecting image edges but it's not working.
All problem are solved except the scaling and moving image.

my code :

```
public class CopyOfPictureEditor extends JFrame 
{ 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6676383931562999417L; 
    String[] validpicturetypes = {"png", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif"}; 
    Stack<File> pictures ;
    JLabel label = new JLabel(); 
    BufferedImage a = null; 
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public CopyOfPictureEditor() 
    { 
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());            
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }            
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar(); 
        JMenu toolsmenu = new JMenu(" File ");          
        final File dir = new File("");
        final JFileChooser file;
        file = new JFileChooser();
        file.setCurrentDirectory(dir);
        file.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        file.showOpenDialog(panel);
        String path = file.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(path);
        pictures= getFilesInFolder(path.toString());        
         JButton NEXT = new JButton("");         
        NEXT.setToolTipText("Next Image");           
        Image imgn = null;           
        try 
        { 
           imgn = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/next12.png"));
        }catch (IOException e) {    
             e.printStackTrace();
        }                          
        NEXT.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imgn));            
        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();           
        buttonPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(250,0)));              
        buttonPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(250,0)));          
        NEXT.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  {          
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {         
                nextImage();
            }
        });         
        buttonPane.add(NEXT);
        getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);           
        setJMenuBar(menubar); 
        menubar.add(toolsmenu);     
        panel.add(label,BorderLayout.CENTER);       
        add(panel);         
        setTitle("Aero Picture Editor"); 
        setVisible(true);       
        setPreferredSize(getPreferredSize());
        setLocation(0,0);
            label.addMouseListenet(new MouseHandler());     
            label.addMouseMotionListenet(new MouseHandler());
    } 
     public Stack<File> getFilesInFolder(String startPath){ 
        File startFolder = new File(startPath); 
        Stack<File> picturestack = new Stack<File>();       
        String extension; 
        int dotindex; 
        for (File file : startFolder.listFiles()) { 
            extension = ""; 
            dotindex = file.getName().lastIndexOf('.');

            if (dotindex > 0) { 
                extension = file.getName().substring(dotindex + 1);                     
                for (String filetype : validpicturetypes){ 
                    if (extension.equals(filetype)) { 
                        picturestack.add(file); 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    return picturestack; 
    } 
      public void nextImage()   {   
        String p;
        File f;
        try{
            f= pictures.pop().getAbsoluteFile();
            a=ImageIO.read(f);
            p = f.getPath();
            System.out.println(p);                  
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(a);         
         label.setIcon(image);          
        repaint();
    }    
     protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
     {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();        
        int x = (getWidth() - a.getWidth()) / 2;
        int y = (getHeight() - a.getHeight()) / 2;        
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.translate(x, y);           
        g2d.setTransform(at);            
        g2d.drawImage(a, 0, 0, this);
        g2d.dispose();
    }
    public enum MouseAction  {
         Move(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR)),
         ResizeSouth(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.S_RESIZE_CURSOR)),
         ResizeNorth(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.N_RESIZE_CURSOR)),
         ResizeEast(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.E_RESIZE_CURSOR)),
         ResizeWest(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.W_RESIZE_CURSOR)),
         ResizeNorthEast(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.NE_RESIZE_CURSOR)),
         ResizeNorthWest(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.NW_RESIZE_CURSOR)),
         ResizeSouthEast(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.SE_RESIZE_CURSOR)),
         ResizeSouthWest(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.SW_RESIZE_CURSOR));
         private Cursor cursor;
         private MouseAction(Cursor cursor)  {
             this.cursor = cursor;
         }
         public Cursor getCursor() {
             return cursor;
        }
     }  
    public class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter 
    {
        private MouseAction action;
        private Point clickPoint;
        private boolean ignoreMoves;
        protected void updateAction(MouseEvent e) {
            int x = e.getX();
            int y = e.getY();
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();
            if (x < 10 && y < 10)      {
                action = MouseAction.ResizeNorthWest;
            }         else if (x > width - 10 && y < 10)         {
                action = MouseAction.ResizeNorthWest;
            }             else if (y < 10)             {
                action = MouseAction.ResizeNorth;
            }             else if (x < 10 && y > height - 10)            {
                action = MouseAction.ResizeSouthWest;
            }             else if (x > width - 10 && y > height - 10)            {
                action = MouseAction.ResizeSouthEast;
            }             else if (y > height - 10)             {
                action = MouseAction.ResizeSouth;
            }             else if (x < 10)            {
                action = MouseAction.ResizeWest;
            }            else if (x > width - 10)             {
                action = MouseAction.ResizeEast;
            }             else             {
                action = MouseAction.Move;
            }            setCursor(action.getCursor());
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)  {
            if (!ignoreMoves) 
            {
                updateAction(e);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            updateAction(e);
            ignoreMoves = true;
            clickPoint = e.getPoint();
            repaint();        
            System.out.println(e.getX());
            System.out.println(e.getY());*/
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            clickPoint = null;
            ignoreMoves = false;           
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)  {           
            switch (action)  {
                case Move:  {
                    Point p = e.getPoint();
                    p.x -= clickPoint.x;                  
                    p=SwingUtilities.convertPoint(label, p, null);                    
                    setLocation(p);
                }
                break;
                case ResizeWest:  {
                    Point p = e.getPoint();
                    int xDelta = p.x - clickPoint.x;
                    int width = getWidth() - xDelta;
                    int x = getX() + xDelta;
                    setSize(width, getHeight());
                    setLocation(x, getY());
                    revalidate();
                }
                break;
                case ResizeEast:  {
                    Point p = e.getPoint();
                    int xDelta = p.x - clickPoint.x;
                    int width = getWidth() + xDelta;                   
                    setSize(width, getHeight());
                    revalidate();
                    clickPoint = p;
                }
                break;
                case ResizeNorth:  {
                    Point p = e.getPoint();
                    int yDelta = p.y - clickPoint.y;
                    int height = getHeight() - yDelta;
                    int y = getY() + yDelta;                    
                    setSize(getWidth(), height);
                    setLocation(getX(), y);
                    revalidate();
                }
                break;
                case ResizeSouth:  {
                    Point p = e.getPoint();
                    int yDelta = p.y - clickPoint.y;
                    int height = getHeight() + yDelta;                   
                    setSize(getWidth(), height);
                    revalidate();
                    clickPoint = p;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) 
        {           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a code sample that will compile? What errors are you seeing?

Comment: @Robert - no sir, there is no error, when i am implementing this code, whole window dragged and i cant'd drag or scale image by selecting it's edges.

Comment: @user2659972 Stop posting questions about the same subject and do what others have already asked many times, provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @GuillaumePolet - yes i know what i am doing but what i will do i don't understand.

Comment: Then provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I have removed near about 400-500 lines from it and then after i have post this required code. other code of brightness, rotate, crop, etc. are removed.

Comment: Please have a look at [LabelResizer](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9thgfdhl7ms455l/LabelResizer.java), though I have taken help from [ComponentResizer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/resizing-components/) by @camickr . Just watch the `LabelResizer` class, the rest is simply taken from the code from `ComponentResizer` from the post, which makes the work too easy :-)

Comment: *"required code"*  There is more to SSCCE than just 'short'.  An SSCCE requires imports, a class declaration, and a `main()` to run it.  It should hot-link to an image, or create synthetic images in the SSCCE itself.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - Sir I have solve it with the help of JohnnyAW. And thanks for your great guidance for SSCCE. Thank You.

Comment: You're welcome for the advice.  Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this one:

```
label.addMouseListener(new MouseHandler());     
label.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseHandler());
```

Since you set your clickPoint in mousePressed and want to have it in mouseDragged, it should be the same object. You should actually get some nullpointers in mouseDragged?

Comment: MouseHandler mouseHandler = new mouseHandler(); label.addMouseListenet(mouseHandler); label.addMouseMotionListenet(MouseHandler); so do you get some NullpointerExceptions?

Comment: no sir it's not working exactly. yes drag works but whole windows it dragging. no i am not getting null pointer exception

Comment: Sir i have added only one thing that Robert have posted me. label.setlocation & etc.

Comment: just tested it, i replaced label.setLocation, revalidate with validate, the listerner thing and it worked for me. dragging is not 100% correct, but this is just coordinate problem

Comment: sir have i to put label.setLocation or not ? one thing is clear that i have to replace revalidate with validate.

Comment: sir it works but problem is that whole window is scaling not image and there is dragging not working properly but it's fine. i have replaced `label.setLocation()` with only `setLocation()` and like so with all.

Comment: you have to put label.setLocation in the moseDragged() function ONLY for MOVE-case.

Comment: and what about label.setSize() and label.validate() ? have i put it as it is or i have to remove from all case.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36109/discussion-between-user2659972-and-johnnyaw)

Comment: do you want to resize only the label or the whole window? if you want to resize the window, just use your code in question, if you want to resize only the label, use label.setSize() but you dont need label.setSize for dragging

Comment: sir is it possible to pass height and width get from new scaled image to paint image again ? means is there any way to repaint image means after each scale image should be scaled, right now scaling is performed on label, that's main problem.

Comment: do you still work with label? I would suggest you create new Class like in the example i posted you yesterday. I would save the initial width and height and then change only the scale values according your mouse position

Comment: sir i have repainted image successfully. now label is not resized , now image is resized. i have made method that take width and height as argument that drawimage using getScaledInstance() method. but now problem is when i resized image from north or south it works but after then when select east or west edge then image again reset to it's original aspect ratio and like that same if i do first east or west then it happens with north and south. any idea why it happens like that ?

Answer (score -1):

Hard to see without complete code, but for one, you're calling `setSize` and `setLocation` on the Window itself in your `MouseDragged` method. If you want to get the object the user clicked on you need to get it from `e.getSource()`, like:

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
    JLabel l = (JLabel)e.getSource();
    switch(action){
        case ResizeWest:
                Point p = e.getPoint();
                int xDelta = p.x - clickPoint.x;
                int width = getWidth() - xDelta;
                int x = getX() + xDelta;
                l.setSize(width, getHeight()); // call setSize on JLabel l
                l.setLocation(x, getY());
                l.revalidate();
                break;
    }
```

Incidentally, why are you using a JLabel for this? I would use a Java object that draws itself onto the JFrame using the JFrame's graphics context.

Comment: sir i have to create new `JLabel` instance or my global instance `label` will work at `l.setSize(width, getHeight()); l.setLocation(x, getY());l.revalidate();`

Comment: How many labels will you have? One? Then you could call the methods on it, but if you want to be able to expand to more than one it would be better to get the source object from the `MouseEvent`.

Comment: i have used only single label in whole application i.e. declared in global part. at each place i am repainting and replacing that label.

Comment: Yeah, try it and see what happens.

Comment: no it's not working i have tried `label.setSize(getWidth(), height);
                    label.setLocation(getX(), y);
                    label.revalidate();`, but it's not working.

Comment: `l.setSize(width, getHeight()); // call setSize on JLabel l
                l.setLocation(x, getY());
                l.revalidate();` That does not make any sense. Either you consider that you are using a `LayoutManager` (recommended) and then setSize/setLocation/setBounds are useless, either you are not using a LayoutManager (not recommended, bad idea) and then calling revalidate makes absolutely no sense. -1.

Comment: Well, I only posted it after a quick perusal of the code, and after the comment that the whole window was moving, so that seemed the most obvious likely place. Downvote not necessary - a comment that I should remove the call the revalidate would suffice.